# Swift 3 (macOS) : keyDown(with event: NSEvent) doesn't get called

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I am trying to write a simple program in Swift 3 where I need to perform an action every time the user presses an arrow key. After a bit of research, I found that the method I needed to use was `keyDown(with event: NSEvent)` ; the problem is that it simply doesn't get called whenever I press any key.

Here's my code

```
import Cocoa

let LEFT: UInt16  = 123
let RIGHT: UInt16  = 124
let DOWN: UInt16  = 125
let UP: UInt16  = 126

class GameViewController: NSViewController {

...

  override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
          print("abc")
          switch event.keyCode {
          case LEFT:
              print("left")
              break
          case RIGHT:
              print("right")
              break
          case DOWN:
              print("down")
              break
          case UP:
              print("up")
              break
          default:
              print("other")
              super.keyDown(with: event)
              break
          }
          print("Key with number: \(event.keyCode) was pressed")
      }
}
```

I tried pressing all the arrow keys, and other key to test if my arrow keys had a problem, but nothing happened - except me getting the error sound from macOS.

I don't know where the problem could be from - I'm rather new to Swift, so it may be something quite obvious that I am not seeing. Do you guys have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Your class must be part of the responder chain.  You will probably find what you need in [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that you've implemented the `keyDown` method in the code of your view controller.  That's actually the incorrect place—that method should go inside the code of the *view*, not the view controller.   If you aren't currently using a custom view (with code you can modify), then you should create a new subclass.

Comment: @Luigi Do you need any help setting this up?